# При использовании Spring Data JPA через DAO, вылетает NoSuchBeanDefinitionException, помогите понять где допустил ошибку

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-jpa, spring-data-jpa

Ниже приведу кусок кода main,ошибку,applicationContext.xml,реализацию dao если нужно что-то ещё напишите, добавлю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что Spring не может вытянуть ServiceAddress из  xml, так как он там не описан.

Если используешь аннотации, то лучше использовать Spring book + Spring data.

[Ссылка для ознакомления](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)

Comment: Пожалуйста, не используйте транслит. Такие ответы сложны для восприятия.

Comment: ну так я же пометил ServiceAddress аннотацией '@Repository', которая является специализацией '@Component', а xml файле тег  <context:component-scan base-package="File"/> сканирует пакет в поиске аннотаций и автоматический создаёт по ним бины в xml, то бишь бин ServiceAddress , поправьте если что-то не так понял

Comment: и вы наверно имели ввиду spring boot? я до изучения его ещё не добрался, хотелось бы разобраться до конца в этом,и при использовании через JpaRepository(наследника CrudRepository) вылетает та же ошибка , я уже пытался настраивать его конфиги как и xml так и в классе с анотациями, исключение одно и тоже, уже прям нервов не хватает, что упустил то